# Compatibilidad entre diferentes frameworks .net en el mismo servidor

Tags: .net

Hice mi primer aplicación ASP, el servidor que me proporcionan para alojar mi aplicación tiene ya muchas aplicaciones funcionando, pero esas aplicaciones ya existentes las hicieron con framework 3.5 y mi aplicación necesita framework  4.5.2.

Si instalo framework 4.5.2, ¿puede que tenga algún problema con las aplicaciones que ya existen? ¿o lo puedo hacer sin problemas?

Comment: La verdad no te podria decir con certeza, se supone que son retroconpatibles en general a menos que hayas usado alguna funcionalidad muy especifica deberías probar y ver que se rompe no queda de otra, o tratar de hacer funcionar tu nueva aplicación con la versión existente en el servidor

Comment: Bueno, ni hablar...más trabajo! :D

Answer (score 1):

Si instalas el .NET Framework 4.5.2 las aplicaciones que fueron creadas para el .NET Framework 3.5 tratarán de correr sobre el nuevo framework.

En general no debería ser problema ya que en general los nuevos frameworks son compatibles hacia atrás con los anteriores sin embargo esto no es 100% cierto.

Algunas características de seguridad y flags nuevos sobre características de ASP.NET que funcionaban correctamente en .NET Framework 3.5 pueden haber sido modificados para mejorar el rendimiento o seguridad y hacer que la aplicación se comporte diferente o que ya no funcione algo en particular.

Si quieres garantizar que las aplicaciones anteriores sigan corriendo sobre el CLR antiguo (CLR 2 en el caso de .NET Framework 3.5) agrega esto al web.config de cada una de las aplicaciones

```
<configuration>  
  <startup>  
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>  
  </startup>  
</configuration>
```

Por último te recomiendo que testees todas las aplicaciones nuevamente en un ambiente de pre-producción con el nuevo framework antes de que lo hagas en Producción, para evitar inconvenientes.

Comment: Muchas gracias, al final a fuerza debo hacer las pruebas.

Comment: teóricamente para esto son los application pool, ya que en estos se especifican la del CLI que debe utilizar el pool, al instalar el framework 4 el modifica los frameworks  de los pool por defecto (Defaul application pool), pero los demas se quedaran con la configuracion que poseen

Comment: Ah mira, eso si no lo sabía.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias...saludos!